# Traceroute and BGP Next-hop

Tags: bgp, traceroute

I just started learning about network engineering and have a very basic question.

From my understanding, traceroute shows the routers along the path that the packet needs to traverse through to reach the destination, and the Next-hop attribute of a BGP routing table entry shows where the packet needs to be forwarded next.

**Does this mean the Next-hop address must appear in the traceroute results as well? (assuming they are obtained from the same router)**

For example, the BGP entry below shows the next hop is 202.158.215.125, but this address is not shown in any of the traceroute records.
[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: "_From my understanding, traceroute shows the routers along the path that the packet needs to traverse through to reach the destination_" Sometimes. Not all devices need to participate.

Comment: traceroute (etc.) relies on ICMP time exceeded messages to learn of hops. If you don't respond (just drop the packet), you don't show up. Also, if you don't decrement TTL (as some firewalls do), you also won't show up.